# Use npm run build serveral times

Tags: reactjs, docker, npm, build, dockerfile

I have a React App and I need to run it in docker. Inside this container I need to build 3 instance with the same code, but with different environments by replacing .env.production with my .env.production2 and .env.production3 file. I have a problem with dockerfile: if I'm not use `RUN npm install` after changing `WORKDIR` - build stops with error:

```
npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.
npm WARN Local package.json exists, but node_modules missing, did you mean to install?
```

So right now it works only with this dockerfile:

```
FROM node:12 as build-box
COPY . /app/expert
COPY . /app/expert-control-chat
COPY . /app/expert-control-support
WORKDIR /app/expert
ARG NPMTOKEN
ENV NPMTOKEN=$NPMTOKEN
RUN npm config set _auth $NPMTOKEN
RUN npm install
# Build
FROM build-box as publish
WORKDIR /app/expert
RUN npm run build
WORKDIR /
RUN rm -rf /app/expert-control-chat/.env.production
COPY .env.production.chat-control /app/expert-control-chat/.env.production
WORKDIR /app/expert-control-chat
RUN npm install
RUN npm run build
WORKDIR /
RUN rm -rf /app/expert-control-support/.env.production
COPY .env.production.chat-support /app/expert-control-support/.env.production
WORKDIR /app/expert-control-support
RUN npm install
RUN npm run build
FROM nginx as runtime
RUN rm -rf /etc/nginx/conf.d
COPY nginx.conf /etc/nginx/nginx.conf
WORKDIR /app/expert
COPY --from=publish /app/expert/build ./
WORKDIR /app/expert-control-chat
COPY --from=publish /app/expert-control-chat/build ./
WORKDIR /app/expert-control-support
COPY --from=publish /app/expert-control-support/build ./
# Start
EXPOSE 3000
CMD ["nginx", "-g", "daemon off;"]
```

Can you tell me the correct way to make a build?
I think that there is another way to build it, but I can't get that.

Comment: Which step fails?  How does the application source get into the three directories you name?  Can you include the _entire_ Dockerfile (what's in the `build-box` stage)?  When `There is likely additional logging output above`, can you include that in the question too?

Comment: David, |'ve placed full dockerfile, but right now I no longer have logs with error. Error was right after second `RUN npm run build` without `RUN npm install`